# Mapping a given value to an action depending on certain characteristics

Tags: dictionary, predicate

Suppose I have a certain value, and I want to do something with it depending on certain characteristics it might have.

For example, suppose the value is a `string`, and I want to print it to the screen if it starts with the letter `L`, save it to a file if it's length is less than 20 characters, and play a sound if the last character is the same as the first one.

One option of course is a simple `if else if` construct:

```
if (value[0] == 'L')
    ....
else if (value.Length < 20)
    ....
else if (value[0] == value.Last())
    ....
```

However with a lot of conditions, this can get ugly really fast. So the other option is a `Dictionary`. However I'm not sure how I can use a `Dictionary` to achieve this.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a dictionary that contains conditions and actions that should be performed if a condition is met. In general, if you need to work with type `T`, this dictionary will have a type `Dictionary<Predicate<T>, Action<T>>`. For a `string` it can be:

```
var conditions = new Dictionary<Predicate<string>, Action<string>>
{
    {s => s.StartsWith("L"), s => Console.WriteLine("Starts with L")},
    {s => s.Length < 20, s => Console.WriteLine("Has fewer that 20 symbols")},
};

string input = "some input";

foreach (var condition in conditions)
{
    if (condition.Key(input)) condition.Value(input);
}
```

In fact, you don't even need a `Dictionary` here - you can use `List<Tuple<Predicate<string>, Action<string>>>`, or, even better - to introduce a simple small class that contains a predicate and an action.

Comment: I see. I though about `Dictionary<Predicate<string>, Action<string>>` but it didn't click without the `foreach` part. I think I'll implement a simple class to wrap this. Thanks :)